# How to right rotate a 64-bit value efficiently in 32-bit ARM assembler?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, arm7

The ARM7-command set (ARM7TDMI = ARMv4T) offers efficient ways to right rotate 32-bit values by an arbitrary amount in assembler. For the 2nd operand of an operation it is even "for free" by specifying `ror #n` as shifter operand, but for 64-bit integers no direct support by the instruction set is given.

Besides the special cases of rotating by 1, 31, 33 or 63 bit positions (not to mention 0 or 32), I only know how to rotate a 64-bit value using *four* instructions ([like compilers do](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A//%23include+%3Cbit%3E%0A%23include+%3Climits.h%3E%0A%0A%0Auint64_t+rotr64+(+uint64_t+x,+int+c+)%3B%0A%0Auint64_t+rotr64_small+(+uint64_t+x+)+%7B%0A++++return+rotr64(x,+5)%3B%0A%7D%0Auint64_t+rotr64_large+(+uint64_t+x+)+%7B%0A++++return+rotr64(x,+40)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Auint64_t+rotr64+(+uint64_t+x,+int+c+)%0A%7B%0A++//return+std::rotr(x,+c)%3B++//+missing+from+ARM+clang+on+Godbolt,+compiles+to+the+same+nasty+asm+as+this+with+GCC%0A%0A++const+unsigned+int+mask+%3D+(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(x)+-+1)%3B%0A%0A++//+assert+(+(c%3C%3Dmask)+%26%26%22rotate+by+type+width+or+more%22)%3B%0A++c+%26%3D+mask%3B%0A++return+(x%3E%3Ec)+%7C+(x%3C%3C(+(-c)%26mask+))%3B%0A%0A//+The+simple+way,+with+UB+for+c%3D0+or+c%3D64,+or+any+c+outside+that+range.%0A//+GCC+compiles+it+identically+to+the+version+above+that!%27s+safe+for+any+c%0A++//return+(x+%3E%3E+c)+%7C+(x+%3C%3C+(64+-+c))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.213822894168466,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armv7-clang1101,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:vcl,ver:%27201%27)),options:%27-O3+-mcpu%3Darm7tdmi+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+armv7-a+clang+11.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:71.41144227475164,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mcpu%3Darm7tdmi+-mfloat-abi%3Dsoftfp+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM+GCC+13.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.786177105831534,l:%272%27,m:100.00000000000001,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for constant counts, using 2x ). In the four special cases I can reduce this to three instructions, but I don't know how to do it in general. So here is my question:

Given a 64-bit value in two registers, say R0 and R1, is it possible to right rotate this value by *n* positions (for arbitrary *n*) with just **three** ARM7 instructions?  Or if any newer ARMv7 or even AArch32 ARMv8 instructions are available, that would also be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a register (e.g. r4) happens to hold the proper magic constant (1 shifted left by the desired left-rotate amount) I think one can do it in two instructions:

```
  umull r3,r2,r1,r4
  umlal r2,r3,r0,r4
```

Slower than using four single-cycle instructions, but even if one has to load r4 with the proper constant it's still more compact than the four-instruction methods.

Comment: Thanks, as one can set up the correct value in r4 in one command, this answers my question! But - as you guessed - I was looking for a more efficient version, so I'll wait for maybe a week hoping for a three-commands-in-three-cycles-solution before accepting your answer.

Comment: You need to chop off and assemble four partial words, and none of the ARM7-TDMI instructions except for the multiplies can write to, nor apply a shift to, more than one register.

Comment: I don't have much hope in the existence of a three-commands-in-three-cycles solutions either. But one never knows. Maybe there is a magic first command which allows to finish off the problem with the next two commands.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution to this, gcc also doesn't recognize it:

```
unsigned long long int reg64 = random_value;
unsigned int n = shift_value;
reg64 = (reg64 >> (n%64)) | (reg64 << ((64-n)%64));
```

results in the following:

n=1:

```
MOVS R2, R0, LSR #1
MOV R3, R1, RRX
ORR R2, R2, R1, ASL #31
```

n=2-31:

```
MOV R2, R0, LSR #n
ORR R2, R2, R1, ASL #32-n
MOV R3, R0, ASL #32-n
ORR R3, R3, R1, LSR #n
```

n=33-62:

```
MOV R3, R0, ASL #64-n
ORR R3, R3, R1, LSR #n-32
MOV R2, R0, LSR, #n-32
ORR R2, R2, R1, ASL #64-n
```

n=63:

```
ADDS R2, R0, R0
ADC R3, R1, R1
ORR R2, R2, R1, LSR #31
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out the gcc. The fact that it needs four commands for n=33 (instead of using the formula for n=1 with R0 and R1 exchanged) shows that is not very optimized for rotating 64-bit integers in ARM.

Comment: In general, the ARM ISA is very hard for compilers. It's meant for use by humans.

Comment: @ninjalj: I'd guess that some human hard-coded the special cases n=1 and n=63 in the gcc.